# Standard way to share and print items in PhoneGap

Tags: android, ipad, cordova, printing, share

I'm writing mobile application using PhoneGap.
This app intent to be installed on Ipad and Android Tablets.
I've HTML page which I need to implement two features on it: 
Share (with other apps - such email, WhatsApp, Facebook, Twitter etc) and Print.

I would like to know what is the best way to do it.
In addition which format is the best to use in order to Share and Print (PDF? Other?)

Thank you,
Moshe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[heres](https://github.com/hazemhagrass/phonegap-print/blob/d4337811eec5667cba85058e7e86d7a1f80d4bbe/README.md) the plugin for printing, and [theres](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin) plugin for sharing

Comment: Hi Marcin, thank you very much. Based on your experience what is the best format to share document in Mobile. PDF? HTML? Other?

Comment: you cant exactly SHARE a document. you can upload it, get link and share the link, so the format is irrelevant.